# Is there a way to create a new Range programmatically, or get the Start and End properties?

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to load and save ranges from an existing Word document.

I want to programmatically create `Word.Range` by `Start` and `End`.

Is there also a way to get the `Start` and `End` properties of Word.Range.

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain a little on your scenario ? .Do you want to directly create a new range from paragraph or words? or something else ?

Comment: I want to track anything from individual words to paragraphs, so I can store it on a backend and load it back into the document. I am unsure if Word.Range is the right way to go.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to get the document content by paragraphs or range , then store them into backend. Then For paragraphs, you can call body.paragraphs to get all paragraphs.

For individual words, you can call paragraph.split() to get all the words and each word is represented by a word.range.